# How to pass several parameters when uploading image to imgur

Tags: qt, image-uploading, imgur

I'm trying to make a function that uploads a picture to imgur and the function is working in the form below but differently then I was expecting.

```
bool ImgurUploader::upload( QImage image )
{
    QByteArray byteArray;
    QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
    image.save(&buffer, "PNG");    

    QByteArray params;
    params.append(byteArray.toBase64());

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl("https://api.imgur.com/3/image"));
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID 16d41e28a3ba71e");

    mAccessManager->post(request, params);
}
```

I was expecting and trying at first to pass the image param in form like this:

```
params.append("image=");
params.append(byteArray.toBase64());
```

But when I do I get an "400 Bad Request" and the error is "Invalid URL".

How can I send several params? Am I using the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at their [Android Upload Example](https://api.imgur.com/#example_code).

If you look at the upload request [here](https://github.com/AKiniyalocts/imgur-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/akiniyalocts/imgurapiexample/imgurmodel/ImgurAPI.java#L35), you can see that parameters are not sent in the body of the POST request (as you are trying to do). Instead, they are **queries that are appended to the URL** (this can be done in Qt using [`QUrlQuery`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurlquery.html)), the **image is sent in the body of the request** and there is no need to encode it using base64 (this is better as it can save some network traffic).

Here is how your upload function should look like:

```
bool ImgurUploader::upload(QImage image, QString title, QString description)
{
    QByteArray byteArray;
    QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
    image.save(&buffer, "PNG");    

    QUrlQuery urlQuery;
    urlQuery.addQueryItem("title", title);
    urlQuery.addQueryItem("description", description);

    QNetworkRequest request;
    QUrl url("https://api.imgur.com/3/image");
    url.setQuery(urlQuery);
    request.setUrl(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
                      "application/application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID 16d41e28a3ba71e");

    mAccessManager->post(request, byteArray);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! 
Though I'm using Qt 4.8 and QUrlQuery was introduced in Qt 5.0 so I have to use QList with QPair but it's working as desired, many thnaks!
`QList<QPair<QString,QString> > urlQuery;
  urlQuery.append(qMakePair(QString("title"), QString("MyTitle")));
  urlQuery.append(qMakePair(QString("description"), QString("MyDescription")));`